# Lua string find - How to handle strings with a hyphen?

Tags: lua

I have two strings - each string has many lines like the following:

```
string1 = "  DEFAULT-VLAN         | Manual     10.1.1.3      255.255.255.0 "
string2 = "  1       DEFAULT-VLAN                     | Port-based No    No"
```

The first string I split into the following strings: "DEFAULT-VLAN", "|", "Manual"...
Then I want to look up the ID ("1") in string2 for the vlanName ("DEFAULT-VLAN") from string1.

I use this code to find the correct substring:

```
vpos1, vpos2 = vlan:find("%d-%s-" .. vlanName .. "%s-|")
```

But vpos1 and vpos2 are nil; When the hyphen ("-") is deleted from the vlanName it is working.
Shouldn't Lua take care to escape the special characters in such strings? The string is handed over from my C++ application to Lua and there may be lots of special characters.
Is there an easy way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume in your code above, the "-" equates to 0 or more occurrences?  If you need to match a hyphen, you need to escape it with %.

Comment: I don't want to match the hyphen - I normally don't know if there is a hyphen in the string. I want to match "1       DEFAULT-VLAN                     |" in string2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua is not magic. All the expression `"%d-%s-" .. vlanName .. "%s-|"` does is concatenate some strings, producing a final string. It has no idea what that string is intended to be used for. Only `string.find` knows that, and it can't have any affect on how the parameter it is given will be used.

So yes, `vlanName` will be interpreted as a Lua pattern. And if you want to use special characters, you will need to escape them. I would suggest using `string.gsub` for that. It'd be something like this:

```
vlanName:gsub("[%-...]", "%%%0")
```

Where `...` are any other characters you want to escape.