# How to use Lua gsub to remove '<!--more--> correctly?

Tags: lua

I have a string that might contains '<!--more-->' and I am trying to remove it by using this code

```
local str = string.gsub (string, "<!--more-->", "")
```

but it doesn't work. The string still contains it.

I try with this

```
local str = string.gsub (string, "[<!--more-->]", "")
```

but it has an 'e' left.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua - get indexOf string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222916/lua-get-indexof-string)

Comment: Also related: [Lua string find - How to handle strings with a hyphen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903085/lua-string-find-how-to-handle-strings-with-a-hyphen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-` character is special in patterns.  You need to escape it:

```
local str = string.gsub (string, "<!%-%-more%-%->", "")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How about gsub(string, "&nbsp;")? Why using "[&nbsp;]" works instead?

Comment: @Joe it does not really.  `"[&nbsp;]"` is insensitive to the order of characters.  It will match all of `";;sp&&&n"` for example.